# Regex error with cirlce bracets in regular expression

Tags: c++, regex

I'm trying to delete all of the instances of ":-)+|:-(+" in a string, but compilator keeps giving me regex error

I've tried using regex_constants::basic ,switching regular expression to ":-)+|:-(+", and switching to c++14 version of MinGW

```
string a;
cin>>a;
regex r(":-\)+|:-\(+",regex_constants::basic);
cout << regex_replace(a, r, "");
```

the code above is even begin highlighted in IDE with "unknown escape sequence "\ )""

Comment: Use `regex r(":-)+|:-(+",regex_constants::basic);`

Comment: Unfortunately, I've tried this before and it doesn't seem to delete any of the necessary expressions

Comment: Do you mean you have strings like `:-))))` and `:-(((`?

Comment: Yeah, seems like I've confused the symbols. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove strings like `:-))))` and `:-(((` use

```
std::string a("Text:-) :-(((here");
std::regex r(":-\\)+|:-\\(+");      // Or std::regex r(R"(:-\)+|:-\(+)");
std::cout << regex_replace(a, r, "") << std::endl;
// => Text here
```

See the [C++ demo](https://ideone.com/kLEX64)

There are two issues:

- The `"\("` creates an invalid string escape sequence, hence the error. To form regex escape sequences, the backslash before `(` must be *a literal backslash*, and to define a literal backslash, you either  use `"\\"` or `R"(\)"`.
- By specifying the `regex_constants::basic` flag, you required the engine to parse your expression as a POSIX BRE regex, and that made your pattern invalid (if escaped) as `\(` and `\)` are used to form capturing groups, or won't match (if not escape) since `:-)+|:-(+` in POSIX BRE matches a literal `:-)+|:-(+` substring.